# Jmeter cookie handling while page redirect

Tags: jmeter

Scenario:

- Login (URL 1)
- Launch link from landing page
- Newly launched link (URL 2)

URL 1 and URL 2 has same domains but different sub-domains.
Have added HTTP Cookie Manager

When I am running my script using Jmeter 3.2 which has only HC4CCookieHandler

Login is passing
Launching the link which has different subdomain is failing, and on verifying there are No Cookies added in the request, here the session ID and other cookies should have been added to the request.

Can some one please help here?

Also added Beanshell post-processor to extract cookies from logon response and added as pre-processor to the redirected request, but is giving error.

> Error: jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

Comment: Add your beanshell code

Comment: For cookies issue, did you try to set `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` in jmeter.properties?
BeanShell error: you need to post script, as well as the entire error (can be found in jmeter log)

Answer (score 1):

1. The fact you don't see all the cookies might indicate problems with the cookies. You can enable debug logging of the HTTP Cookie Manager in order to see what's wrong.

   - Click HTTP Cookie Manager
   - Click "Help -> Enable Debug" in JMeter's main menu
   - Observe `CookieManager`-related messages in *jmeter.log* file

     [image: JMeter Cookie Manager enabled debug]
2. By default Cookie Manager doesn't store "invalid" cookies (domains mismatch, expired already, etc.), if you are absolutely sure your application acts as it should - you need to "tell" JMeter to store this cookie in any case, you can do it by either adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   CookieManager.check.cookies=false

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

   Alternatively you can pass the property via -J command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -JCookieManager.check.cookies=false -n -t ...
   ```

   In this case restart will not be required.
3. In case of manual cookie management in particular and when it comes to using JMeter in the most efficient way in general it is better to avoid scripting where possible. For example you can extract cookie(s) you need from [Set-Cookie response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header(s)

   [image: JMeter Set Cookie Headers]

[using Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter). In case(s) when you have to go for scripting make sure you use the most performing language (which is [Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223))